# Pandas Diff() on first records in timeseries, missing data returns NaN

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

In Pandas 0.14.1 , diff() doesn't generate values at the beginning of timeseries.

Using diff() seems to treat missing data differently than cumsum(), which assumes NaN == 0. I'm wondering if there is a way to make diff() assume 0 for previous missing data (missing because it's from before the beginning time series).

For example:

```
    >print df

    2014-05-01  A     Apple        1
                B     Banana       2
    2014-06-01  A     Apple        3
                B     Banana       4
```

results in:

```
    >print df.groupby(level=[1,2]).diff()

    2014-05-01  A     Apple        NaN
                B     Banana       NaN
    2014-06-01  A     Apple        2
                B     Banana       2
```

When the desired output is:

```
    2014-05-01  A     Apple        1
                B     Banana       2
    2014-06-01  A     Apple        2
                B     Banana       2
```

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, `groupby(...).diff()` just calls `np.diff` which always returns an array 1 (or n) shorter than what is passed to it.

But it should be pretty easy just to fill the missing data.  Something like this?

```
In [175]: df
Out[175]: 
                     d
a          b c        
2014-05-01 A Apple   1
           B Banana  2
2014-06-01 A Apple   3
           B Banana  4

In [176]: df['diff'] = df.groupby(level=[1,2])['d'].diff()

In [177]: df['diff'] = df['diff'].fillna(df['d'])

In [178]: df
Out[178]: 
                     d  diff
a          b c              
2014-05-01 A Apple   1     1
           B Banana  2     2
2014-06-01 A Apple   3     2
           B Banana  4     2
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Hat's off.